# Linked list class initialization error

Tags: ruby, linked-list, minitest

I have `require` for a class that has the method defined. I even have it in an `attr_accessor` which I'm pretty sure if complete excess. But no matter where or how I put it, I can't get rid of this error `NoMethodError: undefined method "next_node" for nil:NilClass`. I'm running `minitest` to use TDD and am super hung up on this point.

*EDIT* I am trying to return a `nil` value when I test `list.head.next_node`

```
require './lib/node'
class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head,
                :next_node

  def initialize(head = nil)
    @head = head
    @next_node = next_node
  end

  def append(sound)
    #@next_node = nil
    @head = Node.new(sound)
    sound
  end

end
```

here is my test method

```
def test_does_head_move_value_to_next_node
    list = LinkedList.new
    list.head.next_node
    # assert_nil list.head.next_node
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedList.new` will invoke your `initialize`; no `head` parameter was transmitted, so the default of `nil` will be assigned. `@head = head` will store `nil` in the `@head` attribute.

Later, your `list.head` uses the (not at all unnecessary) accessor, and returns the `nil` that was stored there earlier. Then `.next_node` is sent to `nil`, but `NilClass` does not define such a method. In order for `list.head.next_node` to invoke your `next_node` method, `@head` would need to be a `LinkedList` object, not `nil`.

If you wish to protect yourself against that, you could use:

```
list.head.next_node if list.head
```

or use the safe-navigation operator `&.` introduced by Ruby 2.3, that will check whether the left side is `nil` and return `nil` if so (and invoke the method if not):

```
list.head&.next_node
```

EDIT: There is also a subtle bug that is harmless in your code but might do something entirely unexpected in some other circumstance.

```
@next_node = next_node
```

Since you haven't defined `next_node` variable in the `initialize` method, Ruby will conclude that you wish to invoke the accessor. This accessor will return `@next_node`, so you end up doing `@next_node = @next_node`. Luckily, `@next_node` already starts as `nil`, so the assignment, although entirely unnecessary, at least doesn't fail.

However, if you defined your accessor yourself, say like this:

```
def next_node
  @next_node ||= LinkedList.new
end
```

(return `@next_node`; if it is `nil`, then first make a new empty `LinkedList`, set it as `@next_node` and return that), then you're in real trouble, because if you now say `LinkedList.new`, you will try to assign to `@next_node` a `LinkedList.new`, which will try to assign to its `@next_node` a `LinkedList.new`, which will try to assign to its `@next_node` a `LinkedList.new`, which will...<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>

Comment: all that will fix the undefined method error? I'm running minitest and jsut focusing on this one step right now. my next step i think is to `assert_nil list.head.next_node` since I am try to get it to give `nil` as a return. Also, when called in a `pry` session I get the `nil` result I am looking for. I just can't impliment it in the code here to clear the error.

Comment: "All that" was trying to fix your understanding: you cannot evaluate `list.head.next_node` if `list.head` is `nil`. (`list.head&.next_node` you can, and will evaluate to `nil` in those circumstances.)

Comment: OK I think my understanding clicked overnight @Amadan. I probably should have slept on it before commenting. I apologize, :P. You're telling me that the way my code is written when run *not* in a test will result in an infinite loop?

Comment: No, it was a hypothetical, if you added the code I wrote. As it is, that line is merely harmlessly useless.

Comment: That did explain though, thank you :D My test was what was messing me up. I wasn't appending anything to it in the test file which meant that it was nil and wasn't able to be read. :D